# Epson Acculaser c1100 installed but not printing on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: printing, epson

Although when sending data to printer the data led on the printer is blinking nothing is printed finally.

Any idea?
Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked on 15.10 also in this page [here](http://ubuapps.blogspot.com/2016/05/epson-aculaser-c1100-unter-1404-64bit.html).